# Calculating weekly growth using previous row value in new column

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a query that returns new customers grouped by week. I would like to add a column that returns the growth/decrease in percentage comparing with previous rows.

I'm doing this in Elasticsearch > Kibana > Canvas so I cant use the lag function.

Ideally my result would be:

```
    Week           | Customers | Perc
    2020-02-15     | 37        | -
    2020-02-22     | 28        | -24
    2020-02-29     | 51        | 82
    2020-03-07     | 51        | 0
```

The calculation to be done is: ((This weeks customers - previous weeks customers) / previous weeks customers) *100

Here is the query i'm running that gives me the results of new customers per week:

```
SELECT  DATEADD('day', 1 - DATEPART('weekday', createdAt), CAST(createdAt AS DATE)) AS Week,
COUNT(1) AS Customers,
ROUND(SUM(transfers.fiatAmountLocal)/360, 2) AS Volume
FROM users
WHERE transfers.fiatAmountLocal > 0
OR purchases.fiatAmountLocal > 0
GROUP BY
DATEADD('day', 1 - DATEPART('weekday', createdAt), CAST(createdAt AS DATE))
ORDER BY Week DESC
```

I need to add the percentage change column to it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your version of MySQL?

Comment: @Serg Its elasticsearch sql

Comment: @CarterBurleson Oh, I see, sorry.